# How to call a function inside of another function multiple times

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, conditional-statements

I am creating a rock paper scissors game where I have a  playRound() function. I am trying to create a game() function where I can call this playRound() function multiple times with different results.

I want to use this game() function to play multiple rounds in order to find a winner
but I am still stuck on getting the playRound() to run multiple times.

With my current code, the playRound() function only runs once in the console.

Here is my code :

```
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  const lose = "You Lose! Paper beats rock";
  const win = "You Win! rock beats paper";
  const tie = "its a tie";
  console.log(`Your selection is : ${playerSelection}`);

  console.log(`PC selection is : ${computerSelection}`);
  if (playerSelection === playerSelection && computerSelection === "paper") {
    return lose;
  } else if (
    playerSelection === playerSelection &&
    computerSelection === "scissors"
  ) {
    return win;
  } else {
    return tie;
  }
}

function game() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    return playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
  }
}

function computerPlay() {
  let choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  let choice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
  return choice;
}
const string = "ROck";

const playerSelection = string.toLowerCase() || string.toUpperCase();

const computerSelection = computerPlay();

console.log(game());
```

Comment: don't `return` in that for loop - since that exits the function in the first iteration of that loop

Comment: This would be a neat application of a generator function.

Comment: Would you guys have any idea how to go about getting the rounds to display different results , and not just repeat the same result 3 times ?

Comment: in the `game` function you are returning a call to the function `playRound` which doesn't exist in the code you posted.

Comment: You used `return playRound(...)` which means it exits out of `game()` function after once call of `playRound();`. You should sum up return values of `playRound()` , not return. Maybe like this. `sum += playRound(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Not only is your game() function returning the results of the round thus leaving the loop... but you are setting the computerSelection only once... before calling the game() function.. so neither playerSelection or computerSelection ever changes.

I rearranged your code a bit and added an overall game score.  Take a look.

```js
function playRound(playerSelection, round) {
  console.log("Round " + round);
  const computerSelection = computerPlay();
  console.log(`Your selection is : ${playerSelection}`);
  console.log(`PC selection is : ${computerSelection}`);
  if (playerSelection === playerSelection && computerSelection === "paper") {
    return 'lose';
  } else if (
    playerSelection === playerSelection &&
    computerSelection === "scissors"
  ) {
    return 'win';
  } else {
    return 'tie';
  }
}

function game() {
  const lose = "You Lose! Paper beats rock";
  const win = "You Win! Rock beats scissors";
  const tie = "It's a tie";
  let playerScore = 0;
  let computerScore = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    const result = playRound(playerSelection, i);
    switch (result) {
      case 'win':
        console.log(win);
        playerScore++;
        break;
      case 'lose':
        console.log(lose);
        computerScore++;
        break;
      default:
        console.log(tie);
        playerScore++;
        computerScore++;
        break;
    }
  }
  console.log("Final Results: Player: " + playerScore + " Computer: " + computerScore);
  if (playerScore > computerScore) {
    console.log("You win the game!");
  } else if (playerScore < computerScore) {
    console.log("You lose the game.");
  } else {
    console.log("The game was an overall tie.");
  }
}

function computerPlay() {
  let choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  let choice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
  return choice;
}

const playerSelection = "rock";
game();
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much for this, my next project i am starting tommorow is to connect a visual front end to this using dom manipulation